# Mapping origins and destinations to the created isochrones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I created isochrones in QGIS using Iso-area as polygon algorithm with an interval of 30 minutes. I have some coordinates related to some origins and destinations. I need to map these origins and destinations to the created isochrones to identify what percentages of them lie within that 30 minutes interval. In other words, if I want to travel from the origins to the destinations what percentage of those trips completely lie within the created isochrones? Is there any tool in QGIS to help with achieving this goal?

Comment: Do you have the linestrings/gpx tracks of these? If you only have points of sources and destinations it will be tricky as the route can vary. What mode of transport are you using? How did you compute the isochrones, i.e. with which service?

Comment: I computed isochrones using Iso-Area as polygon algorithm in QNEAT3 plugin. The mode of transport is driving. I have the travel time from the origins to the destinations based on the road network

Comment: Create shortest paths with that plugin for your source to destinations. This will yield a linestring. If it intersects the polygons, you can divide it at the intersection points and calculate the percentage. Does it make sense?

Comment: This is a little more complicated then I guess. To do this you will have to track the time of the shortest paths. So basically what you will need is the "physical" linestring which belongs to `...some coordinates related to some origins and destinations as well as travel time from the origins to the destinations...` and of each individual segment from start to finish of this linestring you will have to know how much time has elapsed since the start. I think it all comes down to those paths. How did you compute the times from origins and destinations?

Comment: The times from the origins to destinations have been provided in the data set.

Comment: @TimothyDalton Could you please elaborate on your second comment? I created isochrones and its attribute table includes the time intervals. I also calculated the shortest path by creating the OD matrix and its attribute table includes entry cost, exit cost, and total cost of the network which are distances. How can I calculate the percentage using these two data sets which are in different metrics?

Comment: Do you have the shortest paths of the OD matrix? Do you know how much time elapsed from vertex to vertex in the paths?

Comment: The OD matrix only includes the distances. I need to correct something. I calculated isochrones but I need to calculate the proportion of trips that completely take place within created isochrones based on their distances, not the time

Comment: As mentioned above, to do so you will require the "physical" path of the OD matrix combination, how was the OD matrix computed? In QGIS?

Comment: @TimothyDalton Let me ask my question in a more clear way if having physical paths from origins to destinations is the answer to my question, using which tool in QGIS I can compute physical paths from several origins to the several destinations? if the answer to this is calculating OD matrices, which tool in QGIS will help with calculating OD matrices that include physical path? and finally, after this, which tool in QGIS can help with mapping physical paths to the generated isochrones? Thanks

Comment: You could try and use https://root676.github.io/

Comment: I have worked with this plugin a lot. Based on your comments I think you did not understand my question well. Anyway, thanks for the time that you took so far. good luck!